# USB audio ducks when Notifications happen

Tags: macos, audio, usb, mojave, notifications

I'm using a USB DAC (FiiO BTRK3). When my Mac gets a notification, it ducks the rest of the audio for about 2 seconds. It's a big duck too; All the way to 0 it seems.

- It doesn't happen when I'm using DAC as a BlueTooth device.
- Disabling audio ducking in VoiceOver Utility doesn't help.

What can I do to stop the ducking?

I still want the notifications. I still want to use it as a USB device.

I'm on Mojave 10.14.2 right now

Comment: do not disturb mode should help with this

Comment: What is "ducking"?  Does it stop working or does it make strange noises?

Comment: @Allan it’s like going in a low door, duck down to avoid hitting the jam. Audio ducking lowers the volume of the music track so you can hear another sound. Think radio station or a podcast with voice and music changing volumes in relation to each other.

Comment: Is it the Mac that's ducking, or the DAC? [I'm sure I could make a good word-play joke out of that but I shan't ;) ...  test by sending system sounds to a  different output.

Comment: Thanks to @bmike - I know what you're talking about now.... I don't think this is an *issue* per se.  I have this on both Bluetooth and hardwire DAC.  It also happens on non-Apple devices like an Android phone and my car's BT.  It seems to be a UX convention for notification sounds when having to play over/through existing audio.  It's also conceivable that you're not getting it on your BT audio device because not using the *headset profile* (you can't take calls over your audio system but you can listen to music).

Answer (score 4):

The bluetooth receiver was also paired with my phone at the same time as the mac.

I've unpaired the phone and it stops the ducking.

---

I figured this out when a call came in and the ring tone played full blast and started trying to figure out how to prevent *that* from ever happening again.